# Can somebody help me to fix this? Make the output become more tidy

Tags: java

So I'm making a group project which is Java console GUI. This is my code for the Java console GUI:

Here's the output from my code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejIc1.png)
Can you edit my location cause it is so small the text.
Also, the "Disaster Type" I want the category to appear in a list which is Earthquake, Typhoon, Floor, Fire, Other.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class DisasterReportGUIConsole extends JFrame {
    
    private JTextField locationField; 

    public DisasterReportGUIConsole() {
        setTitle("Report Disaster");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        
        ArrayList<Object> reportList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        
        panel.add(new JLabel("Location:"));
        locationField = new JTextField();
        panel.add(locationField);
        
        panel.add(new JLabel("Disaster Type:"));
        String[] categories = {"Earthquake, Typhoon, Flood, Fire, Other"};
        
        panel.add(new Jlabel("Description:"));
        JTextArea descriptionArea = new JTextArea();
        
        JButton submitButton = new JButton("Submit Report");
        submitButton.addActionListener(e -> handleRegistration(e));
        panel.add(submitButton);
        
        setContentPane(panel);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);  
}

    private void handleRegistration(ActionEvent e) { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Report Submitted!");
        dispose();
}
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DisasterReportGUIConsole();
}
}
```

I already created a code for this. Can someone help me to fix it? I tried several times but still didn't get the answers.

Comment: JTextField allows you to supply a character width hint via the constructor. As for disaster type, I’d recommend using a JComboBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [SpringLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) as a layout. While for the list of disaster types, you have to use JComboBox.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import com.example.SpringUtilities;

public class DisasterReportGUIConsole extends JFrame {

    public DisasterReportGUIConsole() {
        super("Report Disaster");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

        SpringLayout springLayout = new SpringLayout();
        JPanel formPane = new JPanel();
        formPane.setLayout(springLayout);
        
        JLabel locationLabel = new JLabel("Location: ");
        JTextField locationField = new JTextField(20);

        formPane.add(locationLabel);
        formPane.add(locationField);

        String[] categories = {"Earthquake", "Typhoon", "Flood", "Fire", "Other"};
        JLabel disasterTypeLabel = new JLabel("Disaster Type: ");
        JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(categories);

        formPane.add(disasterTypeLabel);
        formPane.add(comboBox);

        JLabel descriptionLabel = new JLabel("Description: ");
        JTextArea descriptionArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
        descriptionArea.setLineWrap(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(descriptionArea, 
                                        JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
                                        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        formPane.add(descriptionLabel);
        formPane.add(scrollPane);
        
        SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(formPane, 3, 2, 15, 15, 15, 15);

        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        buttonPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPane, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        buttonPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 10, 10, 10));

        JButton submiButton = new JButton("Submit Report");
        submiButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(DisasterReportGUIConsole.this, "Report Submitted!");
            dispose();
        });
        buttonPane.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        buttonPane.add(submiButton);

        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(formPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);  
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

`SpringUtilities` isn't included in the JDK/JRE. So you need to add it to your project: [SpringUtilities.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/SpringGridProject/src/layout/SpringUtilities.java)